# regex - exclude a subdomain (preg_match)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm want to match a domain (with preg_match) but I want to exclude a subdomain.

Example I want to match all subdomains on *example.org* except *boon.example.org*:

I've tried this:

```
$test = "boon.example.org";
$test2 = "null";
if(preg_match('#(?!boon)(\w+\.)?example\.org#', $test, $output)) {
    $test2 = $output[2] .'example.org';
}
```

But the output of test2 is:
*oon.example.org* and not *example.org*

Somebody has an answer?

Comment: do you need it for "boon.example.org" or generally?

Comment: Generally, boon.example.org is just a example. That is the domain what I want to exclude. All the other subdomains (test.example.org, sub.example.org etc.) I'd like to match.

Comment: is that not a better solution just to replace "boon." with "" ?

Comment: No because I want to match, and not to replace. I want to match the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and If the subdomain is boon then I want him to do nothing. A replace function is not handy here.

Comment: still not clear. If the domain begins with boon, you want do nothing. But what should happen if it does match? Lets say it was abc.example.org, do you want to use parts of the string somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for only that exact subdomain, couldn't you just check if the string `boon.example.org` is present? Seems a bit overkill with regex for this.

Regardless, the following regex should do what you want:

```
.*(?<!\bboon\.|^.)example.org
```

Would return `subdomain.example.org` for all sub domains except `boon.example.org` or any sub domains of `boon.example.org`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want also to match _test.example.org_, _sub.example.org_ etc. Now it returns example.org by that subdomains. See: http://regexr.com?3419o

Comment: I understood from your question that that's what you wanted (just the top domain). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but it doesn't work. See: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?34mte I thought it was me mistake but it matches the first row. Also see: http://codepad.viper-7.com/PlXdnD I'm now using Akam his answer.

Comment: @Gerrit, you are indeed right. I've updated my answer to work as expected.

Comment: Do you also know how to do with `subdomain.example.org`? So that it don't matches `csssubdomain.example.org` because that is another subdomain. See: http://regexr.com?34nmr and http://codepad.viper-7.com/1fsn2j

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
echo '<pre>';
$test = "boon.example.org";
$test2 = "null";
preg_match('/^(?!boon\.)([\w]+\.)?example\.org$/', $test, $output);
print_r($output);
```

This will match all sub-domain except boon.

Comment: That would not match `boon` as a sub domain of a sub domain e.g. `boon.goodguy.example.org` (if that is of any relevance)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will works for you :

```
^(((?!boon).)+\.)?example\.org$
```

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com?3418h)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to match '.example.org' with the regex '(\w+\.)?example\.org' it don't match empty subdomains see: http://regexr.com?3418t