# Symfony 3 requirements regex different from

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I have this annotation for my controller :

```java
@Route(host="{subdomain}.%default_host%", requirements={"subdomain" = "^(?!m$).*$"})
```

I want to catch all subdomains except the subdomain m (which corresponds to mobile).

It works on https://regex101.com/r/GqUVmN/1 but not in Symfony, the controller catches too the m subdomain.

Where is the mistake ?

Thank you per advance.

Comment: Some regex engines don't support negative lookahead `(?!  )`, maybe it's the case for Symfony's?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but could you try this (leading and closing / in the pattern):

```
@Route(host="{subdomain}.%default_host%", requirements={"subdomain" = "/^(?!m$).*$/"})
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer : m is not catched but others domains are not catched either (mario, luigi, etc.).

Comment: Too bad :/ your regEx itself looks fine otherwise. Guess this would be a time for a debugger and a little deeper digging into the symfony router core unless someone can see directly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from an other post [regex - exclude a subdomain (preg_match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245531/regex-exclude-a-subdomain-preg-match)

The working code is now :

```
@Route(host="{subdomain}.%default_host%", requirements={"subdomain" = "^.*(?<!\bm\.|^.)$"})
```